# Installing Nuget not working. Stating 'all specified files must reside in same workspace'

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I have a solution that is on TFS, that I am not the administrator for. I have multiple microsoft accounts, and am currently signed in as one of them.

I went to solution explorer, right clicked, and 'Manage Nuget packages'. I searched for MOQ, which is currently not installed in this project. I have installed easily other Nuget packages previously, but whenever I clicked install here I get this message:

[image]

However, I only have one workspace locally, and apparently one remote one with a different name. What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error and description. This may caused by the conflict of  other account's workspace on your computer. Since you have multiple microsoft accounts.

You can use [tf workspace command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3(v=vs.140).aspx) to list the info of the workspace.

The following example displays the list of all workspaces for all users on all computers that have been created in the following team project collection at the address http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection.

```
c:\projects>tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Moreover, please update your NuGet to the latest version [NuGet 3.3](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) and try again.